# double.Parse throw a System.FormatException

Tags: c#, formatexception

I am trying to parse some string to a double value, using this parse method overload:

```
double.Parse("198.222213745118", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

the CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture is fr-FR.
but this is throwing an exception of type FormatException.

What can be the reason?

Comment: `198.222213745118` should be `198,222213745118` (**,** instead of **.**)?

Comment: Right, but I thought that this is the job of this double.parse method

Comment: use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: No, it can't do it in full generality. e.g. 1,234 is one thousand two hundred and thirty four in England, a little over 1 in France

Comment: If you have control over the string you may want to use [NumberDecimalSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx)

Comment: So how i can do it? I mean - this string is read from a xml file and I get it just like it is (with a ",") how can I parse it to double when my culture is french?

Comment: Thank you, I used CultureInfo.InvariantCulture and it is working just graet

Answer (score 5):

French (i.e. `fr-FR`) use a comma to denote the start of the decimal part, not a period. They use a period to separate thousands.

Comment: Sure, but for this reason I sent my culture to the parse method.

Comment: @user2717436, the culture needs to be consistent with that in the UI control.

Comment: Yes, preciselly, and the thousand separator part is only in written language, the same with Romanian culture. `double.Parse` will not stand for `.` it will throw an exception.

Comment: So how can I do it? I mean - this string is read from xml file, and I got it just like this (with "," separator). how can I parse it to double depends on my culture?

Comment: The XML file should use a specific format. Specify a culture that has a format consistent with the one used in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but my answer might help someone else.
So this is the answer:

```
double.Parse("198.222213745118", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

instead of

```
double.Parse("198.222213745118", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture);
```

Answer (score -2):

I suggest using the Double.TryParse rather than the .Parse as it is safer to use and makes sure you dont get any exception on parsing.

Here is a Code for you to use,

```
double answer = -1;
Double.TryParse("Value", out answer);
```

Now all you have to do is do a conditional statement that'll check if it indeed parsed' the string.

Comment: Very very bad idea due to ambiguity. E.g. what would it do with 1,234?